# ERROR django-softdelete: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

Tags: python, django

I am trying to download django-softdelete~=0.9.1 on a different (windows) device than I usually use through pip. However when run I get the error

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\pelizzy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'im
port sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\PelizzY\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\
\pip-install-32uur6be\\django-softdelete\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\PelizzY\\A
ppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-32uur6be\\django-softdelete\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokeni
ze, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.cl
ose();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\PelizzY\A
ppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-_tq6m_l3'
         cwd: C:\Users\PelizzY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-32uur6be\django-softdelete\
    Complete output (44 lines):
    WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\pelizzy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -
c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\PelizzY\\AppData\\Local\\
Temp\\pip-wheel-300gjngn\\setuptools-hg\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\PelizzY\\Ap
pData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-300gjngn\\setuptools-hg\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'
"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();e
xec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\PelizzY\AppData\Local
\Temp\pip-wheel-3w4e_e8i'
           cwd: C:\Users\PelizzY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-300gjngn\setuptools-hg\
      Complete output (6 lines):
      usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
         or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
         or: setup.py --help-commands
         or: setup.py cmd --help
    
      error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for setuptools-hg
    ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\pelizzy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\set
uptools\installer.py", line 126, in fetch_build_egg
        subprocess.check_call(cmd)
      File "c:\users\pelizzy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", l
ine 364, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['c:\\users\\pelizzy\\appdata\\local\\programs\\
python\\python38-32\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no
-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\PelizzY\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp2i04c4ia', '--quiet', 'setuptool
s_hg']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\PelizzY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-32uur6be\django-softdelete\setup
.py", line 3, in <module>
        setup(name='django-softdelete',
      File "c:\users\pelizzy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\set
uptools\__init__.py", line 152, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "c:\users\pelizzy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\set
uptools\__init__.py", line 147, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "c:\users\pelizzy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\set
uptools\dist.py", line 673, in fetch_build_eggs
        resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
      File "c:\users\pelizzy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg
_resources\__init__.py", line 764, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
      File "c:\users\pelizzy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg
_resources\__init__.py", line 1049, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "c:\users\pelizzy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg
_resources\__init__.py", line 1061, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "c:\users\pelizzy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\set
uptools\dist.py", line 732, in fetch_build_egg
        return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
      File "c:\users\pelizzy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\set
uptools\installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
        raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['c:\\users\\pelizzy\\appdata\\local\\programs
\\python\\python38-32\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--
no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\PelizzY\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp2i04c4ia', '--quiet', 'setupto
ols_hg']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for f
ull command output.
```

I tried installing via `pip install -e git://github.com/makinacorpus/django-safedelete.git#egg=django-safedelete` and manually still the same error. Maybe someone had this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line: `WARNING: The wheel package is not available.` indicates you probably need to install the `wheel` package first.

Try running: `pip install wheel` and then your original install command.